# Correct Parametrization of complex valued line integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone advise me on how to correctly parametrize the line integral of $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{1+z^n}$ along $\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is a straight line of length $R$ and is directed from $\begin{align}(R\text{cos}(\dfrac{2\pi}{n}), R\text{sin}(\dfrac{2\pi}{n}))\end{align}$ to $(0,0)$ and $\dfrac{2\pi}{n}$ is the angle $\gamma$ makes with positive real axis? Thank you.

Here is my attempt: For $z$  on $\gamma, $$ \ z=\left|\dfrac{x}{\text{cos}w}\right|e^{wi}, $ where $w=\dfrac{2\pi}{n}$. So $dz=\left|\dfrac{dx}{\text{cos}w}\right|e^{wi}\ ? $ But if I use this expression, I am unable to obtain : $\begin{align}\int_{\gamma}f dz=\int^{R}_{0}\end{align}\dfrac{-e^{wi}}{1+ x^n}dx.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Along the path $\ds{\gamma}$, $\ds{z = r\expo{2\pi\ic/n}}$ such that
\begin{align}
\int_{\gamma}{\dd z \over 1 + z^{n}}=\int_{r\ =\ 1}^{r\ =\ 0}
{\dd\pars{r\expo{2\pi\ic/n}} \over 1 + \pars{r\expo{2\pi\ic/n}}^{n}}
=-\expo{2\pi\ic/n}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd r \over 1 + r^{n}}
\end{align}